# Changing file loaded from internet to file loaded from internal memory

Tags: android, download, storage

I have decided to not use the internet as much in my app and so need a file downloaded from the internet and then read in the same way. I am stuck on how I would do this as the method I have created already is quite major. This needs to be placed in the internal storage somehow of the android device so the internet is not being used every time the app is restarted.

Here is the code which I am using at the moment to parse the xml file that is being changed into strings:

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML from URL
        songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_GAME);
        // looping through all song nodes <song>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
            <!-- Setting some strings-->
```

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195286/android-write-a-xml-on-sd-card

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a locally stored file the same way. With `Context.getDir()` or `Context.getFilesDir()` you create the `File`object where you get the URL with `file.toURI()`.